# How do I use jQuery Cookie plugin to create a cookie that updates without page refresh?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, cookies

I'm recording the class/id/text that users click on while viewing a page. Anyways, the code below works (with the exception of the cookie value)...

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("div,input,a,select,option,button,img,td",this).click(function(){

        var clickedText = $(this).text().substring(0, 30);

        // Get Element Values
        var elementClass = $(this).attr('class');                       
        var elementID = $(this).attr('id');

        // If element has no class then set var to ""
        if (typeof elementClass !== 'undefined' && elementClass !== false) {
            var elementClass = " " + elementClass;
        } else {
            var elementClass = "";
        }

        // If element has no class then set var to ""
        if (typeof elementID !== 'undefined' && elementID !== false) {
            var elementID = " / " + elementID + " |";
        } else {
            var elementID = "";
        }

        // Create string
        var clickedCookie = elementClass + elementID;

        // Print output on delevopment
        $("#show-cookies").append(clickedCookie + clickedText);

        // Set Cookie
        $.cookie('lastClicked', clickedText);

    });
});
```

I have the jQuery cookie plugin, and currently use it on various other jQuery scripts. With the above, a cookie is created, but its value is something like "`0A%09%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%09`". Is there something in my code that would create a weird cookie value?

It should read similar to the output of `$("#show-cookies").append(clickedCookie + clickedText);` right?

That outputs `la3down | / lc-btn | / live-chat-contain | / live-chat | / contentWide | / frame-wrap` like I want it to.

Essentially, I need to get the cookie's value to read like the above. Does anyone have any experience with jQuery Cookie Plugin? https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/ Am I doing something wrong?

Ultimately I need to have the cookie value update each time an element is clicked... Which means I need to .append() the cookie value as well (i think?). Still researching the _gaq.push command... Pointers on that would be a bonus too lol...

Answer (score 2):

I have done complete bins for above issue. here is demo link too...

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7i

**HTML**

```
 <span>
  <div id="show-cookie" class="cookie">
  </div>
</span>
<span>
  <button id="btnread" class="btnclass">
    Read Cookie
  </button>
  <button id="btnreset" class="btnclass">
    Reset Cookie
  </button>
</span>
<span>
  <div class="divblock">
    Div-Text
  </div>
</span>
<span>
  <input type="text" class="input" size="15" value="InputValue" id="txtinput"/>
</span>
<span>
  <a href="#" id="aLink" class="linkclass">
    My Text Link 
  </a>
</span>
<span>
  <select id="select_tag" class="selclass">
    <option>
      Option-1
    </option>
    <option>
      Option-2
    </option>
    <option>
      Option-3
    </option>
    <option>
      Option-4
    </option>
  </select>
</span>
<span>
  <img src="http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/50305_151863314933391_163751676_q.jpg" id="img1" class="imgclass" />
</span>
<span>
  <table class="table" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
      <td class="cell1" id="td1">
        Cell-1
      </td>
      <td class="cell2" id="td2">
        Cell-2
      </td>
      <td class="cell3" id="td3">
        Cell-3
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</span>

<span>
  <input type="button" id="btn1" class="btnclass" value="Submit" />
</span>
```

**jQuery**

```
    $(function() {

    $("div,input,a,select,option,button,img,td").not(':button[id=btnread],:button[id=btnreset]').click(function() {
        var clickedText = "";
        if (typeof $(this).attr('value') != 'undefined') {
            clickedText = $(this).attr('value').trim().substring(0, 30);
        } else {

            clickedText = $(this).text().substring(0, 30);

        }

        var elementClass = " ";
        var elementID = "";
        if (typeof $(this).attr('class') != 'undefined') {
            if ($(this).attr('class').trim() != "") elementClass += $(this).attr('class').trim();
        }

        if (typeof $(this).attr('id') != 'undefined') {
            if ($(this).attr('id').trim() != "") elementID += " / " + $(this).attr('id').trim() + " |";
        } else {
            elementClass += " |";
        }
        // Create string
        var clickedCookie = elementClass.toString() + elementID.toString();

        // Print output on delevopment
        $("#show-cookie").append(clickedCookie + clickedText);
        //Check Existing Cookie 
        var ckVal = ($.cookie('lastClicked'));
        if (ckVal != 'undefined' || ckVal != null) {
            ckVal += " " + clickedText;
        } else {
            ckVal = clickedText;
        }

        // Set Cookie
        $.cookie('lastClicked', ckVal, {
            expires: 2,
            path: "/"
        });
        $("#show-cookie").show(500);
    });

    $("#btnread").click(function() {
        var ck = ($.cookie('lastClicked'));
        alert(ck);
    });
    $("#btnreset").click(function() {
        $.cookie('lastClicked', "");
        $("#show-cookie").html("").hide(400);
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
span {
  display:block;
  margin-top:5px;
}
.divblock {
  background:#94dca8;
  color:#333;
  width:300px;
  text-align:center;
}
.input {
  border:1px solid #335599;
  color:#335599;
}
.selclass {
  border:1px solid #1122a9;
  color:#1122a9;
  background:#94dca8;
}
.imgclass {
  border:1px solid #1122a9;
}
.table {
  width:50%;
  border:1px solid #2255dc;
}
td {
  text-align:center;
}
.cell1 {
  background:#caa8a9;
}
.cell2 {
  background:#a8b8ed;
}
.cell3 {
  background:#a8bfac;
}
.btnclass {
  border:1px solid #333;
  background:#ada5a4;
}
.btnclass:hover{
  background:#cdcaca;
}
.cookie{
  background:#fda5b7;
  border:1px solid #fa6289;
  display:none;
}
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp7i

Comment: Gonna play with this today. Thank you for the detailed response. This looks great! Even used my selectors :) Thanks!

Comment: This works great on codebins, but when I brought it over to our server, no dice? Am I missing something? We run IIS on Windows Server 2003...http://http://www.horsepowerfreaks.com/js/clickedcookie/demo.html

Comment: In your given URL, js Directory is restricted so that i couldn't be accessed, but please check that you have included latest jquery.js and jquery.cookie.js in your head tag with valid file URL/path...?

Answer (score 0):

Because cookies travel back and forth in [http](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) requests they get [url-encoded](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp), hence a cookie raw value can become different from its original value. Below is an example:

Original value:

> Sunday, 09 September 2012

Encoded value:

> Sunday%2C+09+September+2012

When using the jQuery cookie plug-in you don't have to worry about this because it handles the encoding/decoding for you. However if you are trying to read the cookie value on the server side you may need to decode it. Take a look at [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631683/i-want-unescaped-characters-in-my-cookie-jquery) for more info.

Comment: What sucks is I am using the cookie plugin... I wonder why it is not decoded? @Thomas C. G. de Vilhena

Answer (score 0):

I see where you are going, but `$("div,input,a,select,option,button,img,td",this).click(function(){` binds click to every elements as you select, including those nested elements. So it's likely you are getting multiple values every time users click, not sure if that's what you need.

And as to your question, cookies are url-encoded, you can get the decoded text via `decodeURIComponent(clickedText)`. Next time if you are lost, use `console.log` to trace the problem, a lot.

Comment: I was wondering why it was giving me 4-5 different classes/ids lol. Is it the `,this` that is making that occur? I assumed it would register the .click() on the front-most element. I guess it makes sense that it would fire back multiples though. Any suggestions on how to prevent this? Gonna try the decodeURIComponent() tonight. Thanks for the tip :)